# eslint parse error on first colon in config file?

Tags: sublimetext3, babeljs, sublime-text-plugin, eslint

Using `eslint 2.9.0` with `babel-eslint 6.0.4` through `SublimeLinter` in `Sublime Text 3114`. Since recently `eslint` cannot parse the '.eslintrc.js' at the root of my web dir anymore. Whenever I open a js file I recieve the error:

```
Cannot read config file: /usr/share/nginx/html/.eslintrc.js
Error: Unexpected token :
/usr/share/nginx/html/.eslintrc.js:2
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/require-uncached/index.js:14:12)
    at loadJSConfigFile (/usr/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:161:16)
```

Here is the full `.eslintrc.js`:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "root": true
}
```

What's going on? I don't understand what's the issue..

Comment: i havent used SublimeLinter but technically json doesnt support comments - might try getting rid of the `// look no futher up line`.

Comment: thanks, but I already tried that, and other variations of the config file. eslint doesn't require the configuration to be json anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eslint` apparently expects different formats depending on the configuration file extension.

#### Solution 1

Rename `.eslintrc.js` to `.eslintrc.json`

#### Solution 2

Use the following format for `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    "root": true,
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "jquery": true
    },
};
```